# Outlets for gas range

Tags: plumbing, gas, range

I am building a bay for a new 30" gas range.

**Q1:** I was wondering if there are specifications, or code requirements, for the position of the gas and electrical outlets, most specifically, is there a height at which they should be installed because I know that stoves normally have an opening at the bottom to which the height of outlets should roughly correspond but I am not sure if it is standard or varies by model.

**Q2:** I am planning to install this gas outlet.

[image]

Does the vertical direction matter? In the case of my pipe, it would be easier to install it upside down (if this picture is right side up) because the pipe is coming from above down? Or do I need to install it the way it is in the picture?

Comment: Where the actual connection is, is what matters since the valve itself is in the wall. I would consider setting the valve such that when the gas line is connected it is angled out of the wall to help ease the bend it will need to take to coil up the excess behind the unit.

Comment: Please ask about these two things in separate questions. Outlet height and gas piping rules are not closely related.

Comment: The electrical code says you have to follow the installations instructions submitted to the NRTL (UL) for listing. Take a look at the installation instructions for the actual appliance you will be using, here is a sample, look at fig 4a. http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/012505502415_install.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Typically the gas comes through the floor, so what you are planning may make a difference.
There may be some general tendencies for gas line location, most I see are close to the floor, usually within 6" or less. Whether it is on the left, right or center is usually defined by the maker of the appliance.

To insure the hook ups are in the right place, do your reasearch, check the reviews for the range you wish to use and download the install guide for that particular unit, and set up everything (gas and electric) for that unit. You can't go wrong.